# Which CRS could these coordinates be in?

Tags: coordinate-system

I'm looking at a dataset with polygons for the U.S. state of Kentucky. Most of the coordinate points are in WGS84 lat/longs (e.g. -82.910, 37.873) but a subset of these are in a different projection and look like this 1790295.890, 1125859.117.

I want to reproject this subset to WGS84 but I need to know the CRS I'm projecting from... Any pointers? I know these coordinate points look familiar; I've seen them before but don't remember the CRS they could belong to.

Comment: Maybe `Web Mercator`.

Comment: Have you checked if they're UTM coordinates?

Comment: Without knowing at least an approximate location for one of these coordinates on the map it's impossible to guess the right CRS. Kentucky is just too big.

Comment: What does http://projfinder.com/ say?

Comment: @ArashMadadi Web Mercator x/easting coordinates are negative in the US, unless you're in the west Aleutians or Guam or CNMI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those look like State Plane Coordinates.  I would start there.

Check out NAD83 Kentucky Single Zone first EPSG 3088.  Probably most likely if they are state wide data sets.

https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3088/

for reference a few projected coordinates I always check are state plane systems (NAD83 and NAD27), UTM Zones, and Lambert Conformal Conic for continental us large areas.  Some states like Indiana now have county level systems too, so watch out for that.